# play store rating effective measure of an app quality?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Most of the apps are rated between 4.0 and 4.6. 
How can I judge an app from its rating if they are all basically equally rated?
Is there a way to make a judgement more effective?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should also check the downloads counter, and the number of people that have rated that app, in order to have a better idea.